# Sudden changes in performance

Tags: performance-tuning, system

Last week *Mathematica* was working fine. At the beginning of this week I went on a trip and it slowed down. I ran

```
Needs["Benchmarking`"]
BenchmarkReport[]
```

The report confirmed my suspicions and gave me

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see I am in the anti-penultimate slot with a score of 0.19.

I have just returned from my trip and tried again and I get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So somehow *Mathematica* has mended itself and is top of the heap with a score of 1.89. 
What is happening? Does anyone know what I should check?

Comment: Is your computer a laptop? Did you run it on battery power when you got a low benchmark score? Did you run it on A/C power when you got a high benchmark score? Some laptops go into power conservation mode and reduce performance when the are running on battery-only power.

Comment: Yes a laptop and  run with mains power throughout.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that your unit was somehow in power conservation mode when you ran the low-scoring benchmark.

Comment: On Windows, in the power options there are multiple performance modes. Maybe you been on a different mode for the first evaluation?

Comment: I don't think this was a power issue. I shut down and restarted and looked at what was happening in task manager and could see nothing. Also other programs were working fine.